# What happens if I added double the pumpkin puree in my pumpkin pie filling?

Tags: baking, pumpkin, thanksgiving

I'm a little panicked. I could obviously just wait and see but if someone sees this and can ease my mind...

I used the big 29 oz cans of Libby's 100% Pure Pumpkin instead of the 15 oz cans by mistake. I also added an extra egg as well. Other than maybe a little heavy on the ginger, cloves and nutmeg I basically followed the classic Libby pumpkin pie recipe.

I was a bit confused why I wound up with so much extra filling but I just wound up making more pies since I could. Didn't realize what had happened yet.

My recipe is basically:

- 29 oz pumpkin puree (almost 2x more)
- 12 oz evaporated milk (same as Libby's)
- 3 eggs (1.5 times more)
- 1/2 teaspoon salt
- 3/4 cup sugar plus a little vanilla extract, ground ginger, ground cloves, cinnamon, nutmeg. (roughly same as Libby's)

What can I expect from my pies? Obviously not as sweet and some of the flavors may not be as strong but will it set properly?

It took longer to firm up in the oven but not sure if the oven was having issues or not. Might be because the pie pans were overfilled? I just baked until edges were firm, knife pulled out clean and center was still jiggling.

I hastily mixed up some sugar, cinnamon, ground ginger, and ground nutmeg and spread a couple of tablespoons over the top of each pie trying to make up a little for the lower ratio of sugar and spices.

I don't mind slightly sweeter pie, in fact I usually tend to cut the amount of sugar in recipes most of the time. Can I rest easy knowing I'll have something worth serving tomorrow? Any other advice?

Comment: I think you mostly answered your own questions. I would have baked until the knife came out clean in the center, but relax...you have pie!

Comment: I personally have always found pumpkin custard to be fairly forgiving.  Messing up a measure may make for more/less dense, or a bit more prone to crack, but flavor seems to survive/  in your case, with low liquid, I would expect a bit dense and it might have cracked, but certainly worth eating.  If your catch it soon enough, easy out is add additional evaporated milk or a bit less of heavy whipping cream and make two instead of one.  I have been making with fresh pumpkin, and this is an item that I do not worry greatly about accuracy and results seem very forgiving.

Comment: Thanks @moscafj it came out okay. I was expecting it maybe a little denser but it's hard to tell. Still soft and custardy and set nicely.